# Formatting raw inputs from stored procedure into readable format in Azure LogicApps

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps

I am currently trying to run a email system that will fetch data from SQL and format it within html table to display it for whoever I am sending it to.

The following is my general logic app structure.

---

### [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AR5pW.jpg)

I have stored procedure that filters and sends a column ID (later I'll add more)from which I am trying to create html table. The following is the raw input data received by the "create html table"

This is what my create html looks like.

---

### [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1sGv.jpg)

From: array(body('Execute_stored_procedure').ResultSets.Table1)
Value: parameters('id')

I am not able to parse the raw input to display just ID's in the email.
What should be written in value field for this code to run.

This is my raw data:

---

### [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgQ3Y.jpg)

Comment: What is the error message ?

Comment: could you create a store procedure to return only the data you are interested in ? so you dont have to do any manipulation ?

Answer (score 1):

Is that possible you just use the Dynamic content while creating html table. In fact, I'm unable to use the expression like "parameters('id')". It shows invalid expression.

The following is my general logic app structure. CustomerID is the same as the ID.
[image]

---

This is inputs and outputs of the HTML table.
[image]

From : body('Execute_stored_procedure')?['resultsets']?['Table1']

Value: item()?['CustomerID']

Hope it helps!